# Problems when install perl package

Tags: redhat, perl, rhel8

I am using Red hat (Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.2 (Ootpa) - 4.18.0-193.14.3.el8_2.x86_64).
When I install [perl package](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-baseos-x86_64/perl-libs-5.26.3-419.el8.x86_64.rpm.html) by using rpm package
and command `dnf install perl-libs-5.26.3-419.el8.x86_64.rpm`.
But it requests

```
 - nothing provides perl(Carp) needed by perl-libs-4:5.26.3-419.el8.x86_64
 - nothing provides perl(Encode) needed by perl-libs-4:5.26.3-419.el8.x86_64
 - nothing provides perl(Exporter) needed by perl-libs-4:5.26.3-419.el8.x86_64
```

So, I install [perl (Carp)](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-appstream-x86_64/perl-Carp-1.50-439.module_el8.4.0+646+45e06e4a.noarch.rpm.html)
but it still asks for [perl(Exporter)](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-baseos-aarch64/perl-Exporter-5.72-396.el8.noarch.rpm.html), then I install perl(Exporter), It asks for perl(Carp).

```
  - nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.26.3) needed by perl-Exporter-5.72-396.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides perl(strict) needed by perl-Exporter-5.72-396.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides perl(warnings) needed by perl-Exporter-5.72-396.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides perl(:VERSION) >= 5.6.0 needed by perl-Exporter-5.72-396.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides perl(Carp) >= 1.05 needed by perl-Exporter-5.72-396.el8.noarch
```

Is there any ways I can install perl by pkg or something else locally (I can push file to server but no way from server to the internet)?

Comment: on perl i dont know, but due it tells whats missing, i go install one by one to fixed that in the past. sometimes, its the best to install all at once, however it is requesting perl-exporter in your case

Comment: I know, but the problem is when I install A, needs B, B needs C and C needs A. 
You see, A needs A :))))

Comment: You must install all of the packages at the same time.

Comment: I see. This is the first time I heard about "install all of the packages at the same time". 
But It's work. Both of you save my day. Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option to install a package and ensure all the dependencies are ok, is implement a local repository, this is an offline method to solve the problem.

To execute this [procedure](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-create-local-yum-repository-on-rhel-8-using-dvd.html), you need to follow the next steps.

First you need to upload the OS ISO to the machine or attach it as an external disk.
Once the ISO is on the server, you need to mount as a FS, with the following command.

> mount RHEL8.2.iso /mnt/

NOTE: For the command above, please replace the path and name or your specific ISO.

When the ISO is mounted, you need to especified to the OS that you want to implement a local repo, this will be done moving all the files on /etc/yum.repos.d/

> mv /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo /tmp/

Create a new file on the path above specifying the local repo.

> vi /etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo

With the following:

```
[LocalRepo_BaseOS]
name=LocalRepository_BaseOS
baseurl=file:///cdrom/BaseOS
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
     
[LocalRepo_AppStream]
name=LocalRepository_AppStream
baseurl=file:///cdrom/AppStream
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
```

Now you need to clean the yum repo.

> yum clean all

And load the new repo.

> yum repolist

BR.